# How has data generation evolved over the years (and centuries)?

Tags: data, reference-request, history

I would like to know how data generation has evolved through the years.

My end goal would be to generate a logarithmic line plot showing the ridiculous increase in data generation. Please, does someone have a reference for this? I couldn't find any. It's OK if you point me to a book (available on eBay) that has this information.

Thanks!

Edit: when I talk about data generation, I talk about combined information generated by both machines and humans. I know this is not very well defined, but, for example, before the inventions of computers, you can consider books and movies.

Comment: Interesting question. You can try to get from the Gutenberg project the list of books and group them by year. These wikipedia lists might be helpful too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Books_by_year https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_years_in_literature

Answer (score 1):

You could search on Google Trends all the mentions to generative models. Similarly, you can do something like this on ArXive papers and/or Google Scholar.

Comment: The thing is, I also want to know about the past centuries.

Comment: Could you please define what you mean by "data generation" then, especially referred to a time when computers didn't exist?

Comment: Done, although I understand it is still not well defined.